# Length from nose to end of flight deck / start of cabin?

Tags: cockpit, cabin

I'm trying to estimate this length for the A319-100, B737-700 and A220-300. It is not easy using the drawings, because many cabin drawings don't include the flight deck. I know that it is established by law that this distance is minimum 4m.

Does anyone happen to know what these distances are? Perhaps there are pilots here familiar with cockpit dimensions.

Comment: "I know that it is established by law that this distance is minimum 4m." -> Could you link that law? I've never heard of that and it sounds a bit weird.

Comment: [This document](https://www.airbus.com/content/dam/corporate-topics/publications/backgrounders/techdata/aircraft_characteristics/Airbus-Commercial-Aircraft-AC-A319.pdf) has extensive drawings and dimensions but I haven’t found the one you are looking for. However given the mid-point of the front door is 5.02 m from the cone, the door is 1m wide (so take out 0.5 m), and there’s the lavatory between the cockpit and the door there’s probably just under 4 meters.